# Prove $y_1(x)y_2(x)\equiv1 \iff q'(x)+2q(x)p(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ be an ordinary differential equation, such that $p(x)$ is a continuous function, and $q(x)$ is a continuously differentiable function on $[a,b].$

Prove that there exists two solutions to the ODE, $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$, such that $y_1(x)y_2(x)\equiv1$, if and only if $q'(x)+2p(x)q(x)=0$.

I tried to use Abel's identity, but the algebra got really dirty. I will mention that I tried to prove both directions (independently) and couldn't do it. So I would appreciate your help.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Compute derivatives
$$
y_1y_2=1\\
y_1'y_2+y_1y_2'=0\\
y_1''y_2+2y_1'y_2'+y_1y_2''=0
$$
Insert the differential equation
$$
2y_1'y_2'=(py_1'+qy_1)y_2+y_1(py_2'+qy_2)=2q.
$$
Now again compute the derivative and insert the differential equation
$$
q'=y_1''y_2'+y_1'y_2''=-(py_1'+qy_1)y_2'-y_1'(py_2'+qy_2)=-2pq.
$$

---

Alternatively, deduce that $y_1=e^u$, $y_2=e^{-u}$ with the ODE for $u$
$$
(\pm u''+u'^2)\pm pu'+q=0.
$$
As both sign variants are true simultaneously, the terms can be separated via sum and difference to
$$
u''+pu'=0,\\
u'^2+q=0.
$$
Multiply the first equation with $2u'$ to get
$$
0=(u'^2)'+2pu'^2=-(q'+2pq).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't quite understand the second part of the proof. I don't understand what does $u$ represents, nor where did it come from. Would you mind expanding on that? Also, what about the second direction of the proof? How do you prove that there exists two solutions, such that their product is 1 everywhere, given the ODE for $q$?

Comment: As per the identity $y_1y_2=1$, the value zero is never taken and thus you can define $u=\ln y_1$. Ok, you need to add that you can switch the sign if both functions are negative, or include a sign factor, $y_{1/2}=se^{\pm u}$ with $s^2=1$.